# How to get key/value data from observable in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-template

try to print the key/value from server in angular using rxjs

following is my code

```
  let listener = c.listenFor('addMessage');
  listener.subscribe(mesg => {

          console.log(mesg);

  });
```

but it only print key:

> FIELD_NAME
>
> KVD_VRT

I want something looks like :

> FIELD_NAME:9.02798989742435
>
> KVD_VRT:2.96959280174672

My javascript code works fine,but don't know how to make same thing at angular :

```
        chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('111').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div >').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
```

No idea how dose angular handle,subscribe key/value data.

Any help will be appropriated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Your mesg is an Object.

Have you tried

```
let listener = c.listenFor('addMessage');
listener.subscribe(mesg => {
console.log(mesg.entires());
```

});

Usually

```
Object.entries()
```

returns an array of Key,Value Pairs for every entry in an array

also if you want to display corresponding value to your key, then  in your **Component.html** file use

`<tr *ngFor=" let msg of mesg">
     <td>{{msg.FIELD_NAME}} </td>
     <td> {{msg.KVD_VRT}} </td> 
      </tr>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. but got complain: property'entries' does not exist on type 'objectconstructor'  . after I quick google , it because i use es2016, it need es2017 or find a Polyfill .but I haven't figured out how to add a polyfill.